# Parent Form Opens when Child Form is closed?

Tags: c#, php, forms

I am trying to create a login for a tool which I will be releasing but when I close the child form (Login) the main parent form (Tool) opens.
In my main tool I have this under `Form1_Load`:

```
Login Log = new Login();
Log.ShowDialog();
```

In the child form I have created a simple login form for this example:

```
if (metroTextBox1.Text == "User01") {
    if (metroTextBox8.Text == "Password") {
        this.Close();
    }
    else {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Username/Password!");
    }
}
else {
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid Username/Password!");
}
```

And under the "Exit Button" I have this:

```
this.Close();
Form1 Closer = new Form1();
Closer.Close();
```

But when I press the Exit button it opens the Main Parent Form allowing the user to use it without having to login which is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Implement to Form1:

```
public static Form1 MainFormForMySoftware;
```

When you create Form1 you say

```
MainFormForMySoftware = this;
```

And use this when you want to close the parent:

```
MainFormForMySoftware.Close(); // It's a static reference for your Form1, you can close it from anywhere....
```

It will close the parent and even it's child.

Whit this code:

```
this.Close();
Form1 Closer = new Form1();
Closer.Close();
```

You creates a new instance of Form1, that's not the parent form, that's a new form1...

Answer (score 0):

You need some way to communicate to the parent form whether login succeeded or failed. The usual way is a property. In the child form, add a property

```
public bool Status
{ get; private set; }
```

then set `Status = true;` when login succeeds and `Status = false;` otherwise.

Your main `Form1_Load` becomes:

```
Login log = new Login();
log.ShowDialog();
if (!log.Status)
{
    Close(); // or whatever else you want to do after a failed login.
}
```

(Note that variable names start with a lower case: `log`.)